# CKEditor - Can I trigger inline editing programmatically?

Tags: ckeditor

I have a CKEditor instance with inline editing enabled. It works fine, but I also have an [Edit] button which I want to trigger inline editing (and focus on the text) when the button is clicked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need [`CKEDITOR.editor.focus()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-focus) to do this (see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/aZqL9/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
CKEDITOR.inline(myId); 

function onButtonClick()
{
    myId.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript code to solve : 
focus the ckeditor inline

```
$(btn).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#ckeditor_id").focus();
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.